# Back up contacts, including profile pictures

Tags: contacts, backup, pictures

Lumia 930 with WP8.1

Is there an app that backs up contacts including each contact's photo? I tried some apps but when I open the saved contact file (*.vcf) in Windows desktop, there is no picture.